# Select duplicate and keep the oldest (not based on ID)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, postfix-mta

Thanks for your help i'm stuck on this problem.

Let me explain it, i have this kind of table :

```
| domain |     creationdate    | value 1 | value 2 |
|--------|---------------------|---------|---------|
| abc    | 2013-05-28 15:35:01 | value 1 | value 2 |
| abc    | 2013-04-30 12:10:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
| aaa    | 2011-04-02 13:10:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
| bbb    | 2012-02-12 10:48:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
| bbb    | 2013-04-15 07:15:23 | value 1 | value 2 |
```

And i want to select (with subqueries) this :

```
| domain |     creationdate    | value 1 | value 2 |
|--------|---------------------|---------|---------|
| abc    | 2013-04-30 12:10:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
| aaa    | 2011-04-02 13:10:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
| bbb    | 2012-02-12 10:48:10 | value 1 | value 2 |
```

I tried to do a combinaison of subqueries with IN/NOT IN in WHERE clause and group by/having but i'm not able to obtain a proper result.

I also have another question to ask, if someone already faced this kind of problem i would be glad to hear how he managed to figure it out.

The records in the first table you see above are frequently (every ten mins) deleted/inserted. My aim is to make a copy (or maybe a view) of the result (without the duplicates entries) which will be used 24/7 by a postfix mail server. I heard that big views (with many subqueries) decreases performances which means a table would be a preferable option. The thing is if i have to make a new table every ten mins there will be a little down time and postfix will not be able to read the table.

Waiting for your advices, thanks already.

EDIT :

Based on @Ed Gibbs answer, there is a better sample :

Source table :

```
| domain     |     creationdate    | value 1 | value 2 |
|------------|---------------------|---------|---------|
| google.com | 2013-05-28 15:35:01 | john    | mary    |
| google.com | 2013-04-30 12:10:10 | patrick | edward  |
| yahoo.fr   | 2011-04-02 13:10:10 | britney | garry   |
| ebay.com   | 2012-02-12 10:48:10 | harry   | mickael |
| ebay.com   | 2013-04-15 07:15:23 | bill    | alice   |
```

With your query the result is the source table.

Desired result :

```
| domain     | value 1 | value 2 |
|------------|---------|---------|
| google.com | patrick | edward  |
| yahoo.fr   | britney | garry   |
| ebay.com   | harry   | mickael |
```

I want to keep the oldest domain (with the min creation date) with its own value1 and 2.

---

New question !

I made a view of the desired result based on your anwser.

The result look like this :

```
| domain     | value 1 | foreign_key |
|------------|---------|-------------|
| google.com | patrick | X           |
| yahoo.fr   | britney | Y           |
| ebay.com   | harry   | Z           |
```

I also have a table with this kind of entries :

```
| email              | value 1 | foreign_key |
|--------------------|---------|-------------|
| john@google.com    | patrick | X           |
| john@google.com    | britney | Y           |
| harry@google.com   | mary    | X           |
| mickael@google.com | jack    | X           |
| david@ebay.com     | walter  | Z           |
| alice@yahoo.com    | brian   | Y           |
```

Assume that (in this sample) emails %@google.com from Y foreign_key aren't good records (only %google.com from X foreign are the good ones and also because its domain is the one i choose with the creationdate selection) how could i manage to select only emails from domain/fk referenced in my new view ?

Desired result :

```
| email              | value 1 | foreign_key |
|--------------------|---------|-------------|
| john@google.com    | patrick | X           |
| harry@google.com   | mary    | X           |
| mickael@google.com | jack    | X           |
| david@ebay.com     | walter  | Z           |
| alice@yahoo.com    | brian   | Y           |
```

I tried with a CONCAT('%','@',domain) and a foreign_key=foreign_key join but it doesn't give me what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data and results, a `GROUP BY` will give you the results you're after:

```
SELECT
  domain,
  MIN(creationdate) AS creationdate,
  value1,
  value2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY domain, value1, value2
```

---

**Addendum**: @Arka provided updated sample data where the `value 1` and `value 2` columns have different values (in the original they were the same). That changes the query to this:

```
SELECT domain, creationdate, value1, value2
FROM mytable
WHERE (domain, creationdate) IN (
  SELECT domain, MIN(creationdate)
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY domain)
```

The subquery gets a list of the earliest `creationdate` for each `domain`, and the outer query only selects rows where the `domain` and `creationdate` match the subquery values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried and this still give me duplicates. I will give you a better sample below.

Comment: That still looks like a `MIN` with a `GROUP BY` to me. Based on both sample sets, the query I gave you shouldn't return all the rows. Do the third and fourth columns *really* have the values `value 1` and `value 2` in them, or are they different for each row?

Comment: I updated, they aren't value 1/2 right, i'm sorry. I thought it wouldn't be important.

Comment: Hi @Arka - that makes a lot more sense. Yes, this is important because `GROUP BY` will group for every unique combination of `{domain, value1, value2}`. That's why you were getting all the rows - because `value1` and `value2` made each row unique. I've updated my answer to show how to get the results from your newer test data. If you have any questions about how it works, the first thing to try is to run the subquery on its own - you'll see the set of `{domain, creationdate}` values that represent the minimum for each `domain`. The outer query just pulls from those.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Gibbs, i understand but i didn't thought you would use value1 and value2 in the group by because for me that was just some values without any importance at all in the issue. I did not know it was possible to use two fields in a comparison, i will sleep less idiot :). Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome @Arka and no worries :) I'm glad it worked for you! The ability to do `WHERE (valueA, valueB, ... valueX) IN (SELECT ....)` is really powerful - I'm sure you'll find it useful in the future.

Comment: If you have time i added a new question, i think i'm close but i miss something.

Comment: Hi @Arka, I know it's a pain but can you post this as a separate question? It's a rule on StackOverflow that new questions get posted separately. On top of that, I'm wrapping up for the day so I won't be able to look at this until sometime tomorrow, whereas if you post a new question you should get immediate feedback.