# Performance issue MYSQL SELECT on view

Tags: mysql, performance, join, view

I'm facing a problem of SELECT perfomance issue with MYSQL.

I have two tables "domain" and "email" which contain duplicates, theses tables are frequently updated (INSERT/DELETE) by different sources (every ten mins approximatively).

My primary objective was to make two views from thoses tables without any duplicates. I know a view is a stored query but this is my only way to keep it dynamic, creating a new table without duplicate every tens mins would be mad (maybe not?).

Both views are used by another thread (postfix) to check if the recipient is an allowed one. When i try to do a simple query

```
SELECT email FROM emailview WHERE email = 'john@google.com'`
```

the query takes 3-4seconds. On the contrary if I do my SELECT directly on the email table (with duplicates in) it takes 0,01sec.

How could i improve the SELECT performances on my system to obtain almost similar result with a view and not directly on the table ?

Here is the detail of the architecture (INNODB Engine, value 1 is random and doesn't really matter) :

Domain Table :

```
| field        | type         | null | key  |
|--------------|--------------|------|------|
| domain       | varchar(255) | NO   | NULL |
| creationdate | datetime     | NO   | NULL |
| value 1      | varchar(255) | NO   | NULL |
| source_fkey  | varchar(255) | MUL  | NULL |

| domain     | creationdate        | value 1 | source_fkey |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| google.com | 2013-05-28 15:35:01 | john    | Y           |
| google.com | 2013-04-30 12:10:10 | patrick | X           |
| yahoo.com  | 2011-04-02 13:10:10 | britney | Z           |
| ebay.com   | 2012-02-12 10:48:10 | harry   | Y           |
| ebay.com   | 2013-04-15 07:15:23 | bill    | X           |
```

Domain View (duplicate domain are removed using the oldest creation date) :

```
CREATE VIEW domainview AS 
  SELECT domain.domain, creationdate, value1, source_fkey 
    FROM domain 
    WHERE (domain, creationdate) IN (SELECT domain, MIN(creationdate) 
                                       FROM domain GROUP BY domain);
```

```
| domain     | creationdate        | value 1 | source_fkey |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| google.com | 2013-04-30 12:10:10 | patrick | X           |
| yahoo.com  | 2011-04-02 13:10:10 | britney | Z           |
| ebay.com   | 2012-02-12 10:48:10 | harry   | Y           |
```

Email table :

```
| field        | type         | null | key  |
|--------------|--------------|------|------|
| email        | varchar(255) | NO   | NULL |
| source_fkey  | varchar(255) | MUL  | NULL |


| email              | foreign_key |
|--------------------|-------------|
| john@google.com    | X           |
| john@google.com    | Y           |   <-- duplicate from wrong foreign/domain
| harry@google.com   | X           |
| mickael@google.com | X           |
| david@ebay.com     | Y           |
| alice@yahoo.com    | Z           |
```

Email View (legit emails and emails from domain/foreign_key of the domain view) :

```
CREATE VIEW emailview AS 
  SELECT email.email, email.foreign_key 
    FROM email, domainview 
    WHERE email.foreign_key = domainview.foreign_key 
      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(email.email,'@',-1) = domainview.domain;
```

```
| email              | foreign_key |
|--------------------|-------------|
| john@google.com    | X           |
| harry@google.com   | X           |
| mickael@google.com | X           |
| david@ebay.com     | Y           |
| alice@yahoo.com    | Z           |
```

There is no unique, no indexes, the only primary key is in the table where the foreign_key is.

Thanks for help.

Previous discussion : [Select without duplicate from a specific string/key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802139/select-without-duplicate-from-a-specific-string-key)

Comment: how many records are there?

Comment: In my test environnement only 60 domains and 130'000 emails, in the production one i'm expecting about 500'000 mails and 10'000 domains ~.

Comment: I tried to improve the cache and it does nothing. I think the problem is the views because in a direct query on the source table the response is quite fast (0,01sec).

When i'm doing a query on "emailview" like this : SELECT email FROM emailview WHERE email = 'john@google.com'; it takes 4 seconds which is really slow for a mail server.

Comment: Each time you query the view, it is "recreated". I think in your case you should be better off querying the original tables (since you are only interested in one single entry/email). The view would make sense only if you neede to retrieve the associated keys for all/many emails with each query. If you are looking for a way to automate this (in order to simplify your queries) a function might be what you are looking for.

Comment: With your advice i made a single request and the time is almost the same (4,59s with view, 4,47s without).

Comment: > SELECT email 
>  FROM email, 
>   (SELECT domain, creationdate 
>    FROM domain 
>     WHERE (domain, creationdate) 
>      IN (SELECT domain, MIN(creationdate) 
>       FROM domain GROUP BY domain) as Temp 
> WHERE email.source_fkey=Temp.source_fkey 
>  AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(email.email,'@',-1) = Temp.domain;

Comment: @Arka: Previously, you said "a direct query on the source table the response is quite fast (0,01sec)". How did that now got to 4,47s ??? Maybe you misunderstood me. What do you mean by "a single request" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both queries are slow - first because of the subselect in the `IN` clause - which is not optimized until MySQL 5.6; the second because uses a function in the where clause.

In the first query you can replace the subselect with a join
In the second, it's best to store the domain in separate column and use it for comparision

Make sure you have composite indexes on the fields used in joins, where and group by clauses

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the first query, i will use direct queries instead of making queries on a view to improve my perfs.

Comment: @Arka You are wrong. Multiple connections just kill your server instead to getting all data at once. I came to correct some code wrote into your style(around 2 weeks ago) which took around 50-90s to execute around 1k queries instead writing a correct query executed 1 time and taking all the info which took around 1s(cause I was using the indexes and joins instead). Remember: This is my particular case; but my opinion is to get a DBA opinion instead killing the server with multiple connection to the DB(in special if the DB engine is InnoDB).